# How to create shaded path in d3 and SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am creating a chart with shading effects and would like to have a line graph with an effect similar to [this](https://lesposen.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/img_2999.png) one from Apple's Health kit, except without the sharp vertical line after the last data point. Essentially I want shading below a line that is the shape of the line,rather like a very blurry drop shadow. How could this be achieved in d3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the graph line, you will need to create a polygon which you place behind the line.  Give that polygon a linear gradient.  The gradient colour is white and varies from semitransparent at the top to totally transparent at the bottom.

Demo below.  I'll leave you to convert this to d3.

```html
    <svg width="750" height="384">
      <defs>
        <!-- The below-the-graph gradient fill -->
        <linearGradient id="grad" x2="0" y2="1">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.5"/>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <filter id="blur">
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" />
        </filter>
      </defs>

      <!-- The orange background -->
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="734" height="368" rx="14" fill="#ff7744"/>

      <!-- This transform just moves the graph from the origin (top left) onto the orange background -->
      <g transform="translate(80,134)">

        <!-- Same shape as the graph but adds points at bottom right and bottom left to complete the polygon -->
        <polygon fill="url(#grad)" filter="url(#blur)"
                 points="0,127, 90,85, 180,115, 270,47, 360,143, 450,0
                         450,177, 0,177"/>

        <!-- The white graph line goes last (on top) -->
        <polyline fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="3"
                  points="0,127, 90,85, 180,115, 270,47, 360,143, 450,0"/>
      </g>
      
    </svg>
```

**Update**

Sorry, I must have missed your point about blurring the gradient under the line.  I've added a bit of blur to my example to show you what a blur filter can do.  It is just a quick hack and you can see how it bleeds above the line.  To fix that you would need to make a mask or clip-path to mask out the area above the line, so that bleed is not visible.

Comment: Thankyou! The basic strategy is good, but my core problem is how to soften the vertical lines on the right and left sides of the polygon. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You would add a blur filter to the <g> element with a small standard deviation.

Comment: Just by itself, that wouldn't work. You would need to mask off the area above the graph line, otherwise the blur would be visible where you didn't want it.